Why XML.toJSONObject (Kotlin) doesn't work?
My code:
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.XML

fun xml_to_json() {
    val xml = """
        <Author>
            <address>
                <street>Internet Broadline</street>
                <postcode>123456</postcode>
            </address>
            <name>bezkoder</name>
            <age>26</age>
        </Author>
    """
    try {
        Log.d("OK", "OK")
        val obj = XML.toJSONObject(xml)
        Log.d("OK2", "OK2")
        Log.d("JSON", obj.toString(4))
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.d("NOT_OK", "NOT_OK")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

The output is only "OK", but no second "OK2". So it won't pass 'val obj = XML.toJSONObject(xml)', but also it doesn't returns an error. What am I doing wrong?

How are you running that code? Could it be throwing some other type of exception?  Alternatively, could the later logs be truncated if it exits without flushing the log stream?

@gidds I was running the code in a for loop. If I don't do that, than I do get a Fatal Exeption: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (Ljava/io/Reader;)V in class Lorg/json/JSONTokener; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.json.JSONTokener' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar). I think it has to do with link. But I still don't have the solution.

That error looks like your real problem.  (Running it in a loop wouldn't prevent that error; maybe your surrounding code was hiding it?)  And it looks like a library/build problem, not a coding problem.  Perhaps you could open a separate question, giving a minimal, reproducible example and including the POM or Gradle file or whatever you used to build it?
